# Is there a way of saving the current record of a database to a variable?

Tags: delphi

In delphi 10.3, I have a database being displayed on a dbGrid. I need to display certain fields from the selected record onto another form. I'm not sure if I need to save the selected record to a variable and declare that as a global variable, then call that global variable in the next form? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful. Is the second form automatically created or do you create it yourself? Do you want to display the second form modally or non-modally? Exactly how do you want "display" the data? What kind of fields are there?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your q is yes, you can do that and it's actually very simple to do.

Database access in Delphi is based on an abstracted model of a dataset (TDataSet) which,
if it is not empty, has a logical cursor which designates exactly one record as the selected
(or "current") one, and there are various methods (First, Last, Next, Prior, etc, etc) to move
the cursor around to access other records.  You can access the values in the fields of the current
record by calls such as

```
SomeString := Table1.FieldByName('FirstName').AsString;
```

However, Delphi comes with a complete set of "db-aware" controls (see the Component Palette `Data Access` tab) for displaying and allowing on-screen editing of record data without requiring any code to be written, at least for simple editing operations.

The details of this are way beyond the scope of an SO answer like this, but you won't have any trouble
finding yourself a tutorial on the subject, and you really need to do that.

A TBGrid displays several adjacent (in access order) records from the dataset which feeds it
via a TDataSource component, which insulates the TDBGrid from the particular dataset set you are using
(there are many libraries of TDataSet-descendant types for use with different database types and
DBMSs.  A handy thing (particularly from your point of view) is that the coding of TDBGrid ensures
that the selected row in the grid (or, strictly, one of them because the grid supports multiply-selected
records) is the one whichthe dataset's cursor is on.

So, the simplest way to achieve what you want is:

- Add a TDataSource to your second form, and connect its DataSet property to the dataset that's feeding
  your TDBGrid.
- Add db-aware controls such as TDBEdit and TDBText to your form,
  connect them in the Object Inspector to your added TDataSource and set their FieldName properties to the names
  of the fields you want to display.
- And that's all there is to it, really - there's no messing about with global variables as you
  seemed to be envisaging.

Comment: Did this answer your q or not?